# How to parse the JSON response?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I am working on a project where the facebook's friend list have to de displayed. I did all necessary coding to get the reponse , but the reponse is like the following

```
 {"data":[{"name":"Ramprasad Santhanam","id":"586416887"},{"name":"Karthik Bhupathy","id":"596843887"},{"name":"Anyembe Chris","id":"647842280"},{"name":"Giri Prasath","id":"647904394"},{"name":"Sadeeshkumar Sengottaiyan","id":"648524395"},{"name":"Thirunavukkarasu Sadaiyappan","id":"648549825"},{"name":"Jeethendra Kumar","id":"650004234"},{"name":"Chandra Sekhar","id":"652259595"}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to save name and id in two different arrays.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can see below how html response parse . there i am getting facebook friends.

```
- (void)fbGraphCallback:(id)sender 

    {

    if ( (fbGraph.accessToken == nil) || ([fbGraph.accessToken length] == 0) )


 {

            //restart the authentication process.....
    [fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) 
                         andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins"];

} 
else 

{

    NSLog(@"------------>CONGRATULATIONS<------------, You're logged into Facebook...  Your oAuth token is:  %@", fbGraph.accessToken);
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/friends" withGetVars:nil];// me/feed 
    //parse our json
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *   facebook_response = [parser objectWithString:fb_graph_response.htmlResponse error:nil]; 
    //init array 
    NSMutableArray * feed = (NSMutableArray *) [facebook_response objectForKey:@"data"];
    //  NSMutableArray *recentFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //adding values to array
    for (NSDictionary *d in feed) 
    {
        [arr addObject:d];


    }

    //NSLog(@"array is %@ ",arr);
    [fbSpinner stopAnimating];
    [fbSpinner removeFromSuperview];

    [myTableView reloadData];


}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is json response you are getting. So you need a JSON parser to convert this string into Objective-C objects. In iOS App, you can use a library like the [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/).  This library will allow you to easily parse JSON and generate json from dictionaries / arrays (that's really all JSON is composed of).

From SBJson docs: After JSON parsing you will get this conversion

> JSON is mapped to Objective-C types in the following way:
>
> - null    -> NSNull
> - string  -> NSString
> - array   -> NSMutableArray
> - object  -> NSMutableDictionary
> - true    -> NSNumber's -numberWithBool:YES
> - false   -> NSNumber's -numberWithBool:NO
> - integer up to 19 digits -> NSNumber's -numberWithLongLong:
> - all other numbers       -> NSDecimalNumber

Answer (score 2):

That looks like JSON, not HTML.  (You probably already knew this, since you tagged the question with `json` I see.)

I'm not really sure why others are recommending third-party libraries to do this, unless you need to support rather old OS releases.  Just use Apple's built-in [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
class.

Answer (score 1):

This is not HTML. This is JSON. You'll need a [JSON parser](http://github.com/H2CO3/CarbonateJSON) for this.

A JSON parser would typically make an NSDictionary or NSArray out of the string. With my implementation, you'd do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *ids = [NSMutableArray array];

NSDictionary *root = [responseString parseJson];
NSArray *data = [root objectForKey:@"data"];
for (NSDictionary *pair in data)
{
    [names addObject:[pair objectForKey:@"name"]];
    [ids addObject:[pair objectForKey/@"id"]];
}
```

Recent versions of iOS contain a new Foundation class, `NSJSONSerialization`, that will handle any JSON parsing and serialization for you.

Comment: Can you please tell me the sample code for parsing this, because im new to this

Comment: @surrender added sample code, but please **try to understand how it works**. Thanks.